# post param usage for SWFUpload?

Tags: php, flash, swfupload

hi can someone explain how the post_param is used in SWFUpload. i need the value for name='batchid' loaded when i submit. this is what the example doc shows

```
post_params : {
    "post_param_name_1" : "post_param_value_1",
    "post_param_name_2" : "post_param_value_2",
    "post_param_name_n" : "post_param_value_n"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
post_params : {
    "name" : "batchid"
}
```

If batchid is a variable (I'm guessing so) define it using your php and call it as a normal js var:

```
post_params : {
    "name" : batchid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add POST variables after  initialisation SWFUPLOAD:

```
        var form = document.adminForm;
        if (form.catid.value == "0"){
    alert( "<?php echo JText::_( 'You must select a category', true ); ?>" );
       } else {
          var radio =  $('adminForm').value;    
          upload1.addPostParam("published" ,radio),
          upload1.addPostParam("cat_id" , document.adminForm.catid.value );
          upload1.addPostParam("MAX_FILE_SIZE" ,"5000000" );
          upload1.addPostParam("UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE" ,"5000000" );
      upload1.startUpload();
      }


            var upload1;
        window.onload = function() {
    upload1 = new SWFUpload({
    post_params: {},
        upload_url: "upload.php", 
            file_size_limit : "1024",
             ...

             })
```